# Is there any way we can monitor all data modifications in intersystems cache?

Tags: intersystems-cache

I'm a newbie of intersystems cache. We have an old system using cache database, now we want to extract and transform all data of it to store into another different database such as PostgreSQL first, and then  monitor all modifications of the original cache data to modify(new or update) our transformed data in PostgreSQL in time.

Is there any way we can monitor all data modifications in cache?

Does cache have got any modification/replication log just like mongodb's oplog?

Any idea would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In short, yes, there is a way to monitor data modifications. InterSystems uses [journaling](https://docs.intersystems.com/irislatest/csp/docbook/DocBook.UI.Page.cls?KEY=GCDI_journal) for some reasons, mostly related to keeping data consistent. In some situations, journals may have more records than in others. It used to rollback transactions, restore data in unexpected shutdowns, for backups, for mirroring, and so on.

But I think in your situation it may help. Most of the quite old applications on Caché does not use Objects and SQL tables and works just with globals as is. While in journals you will find only globals, so, you if already have objects and tables in your Caché application, you should know where and how it stores data in globals. And with [Journals API](https://docs.intersystems.com/irislatest/csp/documatic/%25CSP.Documatic.cls?&LIBRARY=%25SYS&CLASSNAME=%25SYS.Journal.File) you will be able to read every change in the data. There will be any changes, if the application uses transactions, you will have flags about it as well. Every record changes only one value, it could be set or kill.

And be aware, that Caché cleans outdated journal files by settings, so, you have to increase the number of days after which it will be purged.